# substitute n'th expression with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to substitute the n'th expression seperated by spaces in a line similiar to:

```
%ABC 999 123 "-234" AAA
%999 123 "ABC" 456 BBB
```

There is no rule to what each expression can contain, only that it is seperated by a space. I need to substitute the n'th (for the sake of the example, say the 4th expression) with a given string, for example: (change the 4th expression to 666)

```
%ABC 999 123 "-234" AAA  ----> %ABC 999 123 666 AAA
%999 123 "ABC" 456 BBB ------> %999 123 "ABC" 666 BBB
```

I'm using linux, I could not get sed to do it.. i tried grepping for %(.* ){5} and other attempts, but i could not get it running...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that awk is more appropriate in this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ awk '{$4=666}1' file
%ABC 999 123 666 AAA
%999 123 "ABC" 666 BBB

$ sed 's/[^ ]\+/666/4' file
%ABC 999 123 666 AAA
%999 123 "ABC" 666 BBB
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\S+/666/4' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here`s a oneliner that might be useful .

Assumptions :

```
string='%ABC 999 123 "-234" AAA'
new_val=666
element=4
```

Trying to replace the 4th element can be done in bash using "sed" and "cut"

```
replaced_string=$(echo ${string} | sed "s%$(echo ${string} | cut -d\  -f${element})%${new_val}%")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't hard code the strings into the script as I've got 9000 of them,  I need it to be changed on a given file